# ZSH: Recursive globbing excluding specified hidden directories

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I thought the glob pattern:

```
**/(*|.*)
```

would represent every folder and file starting with dot (`.`) or not, but it skips directories in the current directory that start with `.`.

What is the glob pattern that means:

> every file and folder that may or may not start with `.` on the
>   current and deeper folders

**Also:** How can I exclude a specific folder (or even better, a glob subpattern) from a recursive glob pattern such as the one above?

I have tried the following to exclude the folder `.hg` from the current level (but include other folders starting with the `.` character):

```
**~.hg/*
```

but it didn't go recursively into deeper directories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to make a glob pattern match dot files is to use the `D` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
**/*(D)
```

The precedence of `~` is lower than `/`, so `**~.hg/*` is `**` minus the matches for `.hg/*`. But `**` is only special if it's before a `/`, so here it matches the files in the current directory. To exclude `.hg` and its contents, you need

```
**/*~.hg~.hg/*(D)
```

Note that zsh will still traverse the `.hg` directory, which can take some time; this is a limitation of `**`: you can't set an exclusion list directly at this level.

Answer (score 5):

`**/*(D)` (short for `(*/)#*(D)`) includes dotfiles and dotdirs as already said.

If you want to exclude `.hg` directories at every level, you need:

```
(^.hg/)#^.hg(D)
```

(you need `setopt extendedglob` for the `^` and `#` operators)

As already said, the `~pattern` will exclude entries (based on whether their full expansion matches "pattern" **after** the list has been generated, so will not stop it to descend into subdirs).