# How can I make zsh globbing ignore files like .DS_Store

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Most of the time I enjoy the combination of (on the one hand) running zsh on a BSD variant in iTerm, but (on the other hand) having the macOS experience available for apps that don't run or don't make as much sense to run in a terminal.

But one thing that drives me crazy are the horrible `.DS_Store` files that macOS dumps all over the place.

Can I configure zsh so that if I type (for example) `nvim *`<kbd>tab</kbd>, the `*` is expanded without including any files I wish to avoid?  (That could include `.DS_Store`, `Icon?`, and potentially others I can't think of right now.)

I'm not asking how I can construct a pattern on the spot that excludes certain files (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23407799/241142), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27131/3358), and [here](https://itectec.com/unixlinux/zsh-recursive-globbing-excluding-specified-hidden-directories/)) but how I can make all globs always exclude certain files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't customize globbing itself except for the `dot_glob` option. That's one of the few features that exists in ATT ksh and in bash but not in zsh. So `echo *` will always show `Icon1`.

You can ignore patterns in completion, but it gets complicated when wildcards are involved. Let's start with something simple: completion not involving wildcards. With the following `.zshrc`, file like `.DS_Store` and `Icon1` will not be offered for completion unless there are no matches otherwise.

```
autoload -zU compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion::complete:*:*:files' ignored-patterns '.DS_Store' 'Icon?'
zstyle ':completion::complete:*:*:globbed-files' ignored-patterns '.DS_Store' 'Icon?'
zstyle ':completion::complete:rm:*:globbed-files' ignored-patterns
```

Explanation: I define [completion styles](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-1):

- They apply whenever doing completion.
- They apply when the “function” is empty (this excludes some special widgets).
- They apply when doing ordinary completion ([`_complete`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fcomplete)), as opposed to e.g. correction or [`_ingore`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fignore).
- They apply to any command except `rm`. For the `rm` command, the snippet above defines an empty ignore list, which overrides the default.
- They apply to any position on the command line.
- They apply when collecting file names (through either the tag [`_files`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-all_002dfiles_002c-completion-tag) or the tag [`_globbed-files`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-all_002dglobbed-files_002c-completion-tag)).

These styles don't apply for wildcard expansion. By default, wildcard expansion on <kbd>Tab</kbd> bypasses the completion code. To make it use the completion code, specifically the [`_expand` completer](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fexpand), you need to bind <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `complete-word` and use the `_expand` completer, which uses the `expansions` tag.

```
autoload -zU compinit
compinit
bindkey '^I' complete-word
zstyle ':completion:::::' completer _expand _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion::expand:*:*:expansions' ignored-patterns '.DS_Store' 'Icon?'
zstyle ':completion::expand:*:*:all-expansions' ignored-patterns '.DS_Store' 'Icon?'
```

With this `.zshrc`, in a directory containining `.DOH`, `.DS_Store` and `.zshrc`, `echo .*`<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through `.DOH`, `.zshrc`, `.DOH .DS_Store .zshrc` and `.*`. Thanks to the `ignored-patterns` style on the `expansions` tag, `.DS_Store` is ignored when cycling through individual expansions. There is an `all-expansions` tag which applies when expanding to the list of matches, but unfortunately it doesn't support `ignored-patterns`. (Actually, it kind of does, but in a useless way: the it can be used to remove the whole list of matches, not to remove individual elements from it.)

The only way I've found to filter out matches from the list of all expansions is to patch the [`_expand` function](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/ee1d622042015d9eb56bfd616163e82ffb7e5b4f/Completion/Base/Completer/_expand).

```
diff --git a/Completion/Base/Completer/_expand b/Completion/Base/Completer/_expand
index e5e4f9b39..df6f55a7d 100644
--- a/Completion/Base/Completer/_expand
+++ b/Completion/Base/Completer/_expand
@@ -107,7 +107,13 @@ subd=("$exp[@]")
 integer done_quote
 local -a orig_exp=( $exp )
 if [[ "$force" = *g* ]] || zstyle -T ":completion:${curcontext}:" glob; then
-  eval 'exp=( ${~exp//(#b)\\([     \"'"\'"'
+  local -a exps igns
+  exps=($~exp)
+  zstyle -a ":completion:${curcontext}:all-expansions" ignored-patterns igns
+  if (($#igns)); then
+    eval "exps=(\${exps:#(${(j:|:)igns})})"
+  fi
+  eval 'exp=( ${exps//(#b)\\([     \"'"\'"'
 ])/$match[1]} ); exp=( ${(q)exp} )' 2>/dev/null && (( $#exp )) && done_quote=1
 fi
 # If the globbing failed, or we didn't try globbing, we'll do
```

With this patch and the `.zshrc` above, the `all-expansions` tag does cause `.DS_Store` to be ignored by `echo .*` <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Beware that I've only minimally tested this patch. It may break other things. It may not work in some configurations. It may not quote file names properly.

Comment:  You sir are a treasure!  